# How to output mongoose/mongodb query with date fields that print strings with specific format?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm querying mongoDB via mongoose for some items that have fields of `Date` type.

I'm passing the result of this query to express as a web response. Somewhere, this `Date` is being converted to a string. The output is `"2016-09-28T03:19:51.066Z"`.

I want to choose the format of this string. For the sake of a concrete example, let's say all I want is `Date.getFullYear()`. This should return `"2016"` instead of `"2016-09-28T03:19:51.066Z"`.

Iterating over the query result is not a solution.

I tried using mongoose virtual methods with some schema options to no avail. I couldn't find anything that would intercept the stringification of this `Date` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can you the aggregation operator [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

do something like:

```
db.table.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project: {
          fullYear: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y", date: "$date" } }
       }
     }
   ]
)
```

where $date is your date field.

If you just want it like year only in your frontend, you can also override the toJSON method and to a date.getFullYear() there.

include the below in your model:

```
YourSchema.set('toJSON', {
    transform: function (doc, ret, options) {
        if (ret.date) {
          ret.date = ret.date.getFullYear();
        }

        return ret;
    }
});
```

You have to keep that when you add a field to your model you have to include it in the toJson, else it's not included ;-)

Comment: I was checking out aggregation but it seemed like the wrong tool, and is more complex than I believe a solution for this should be. Overriding toJSON is also not quite the right thing, unless theres some added magic I'm missing. A query can select specific fields & you could have more than one Date field, but only want a specific one changed. How do you keep O(1) while still getting the one specific 'date' field to output proper?

Comment: Well the aggregation is not the wrong tool, it's a very powerful function of mongodb, i'll add an toJson sample to my answer

Comment: This toJSON is the right thing, and I was just not getting it until you helped! One thing I changed was to keep ret and just change the field I need, so I don't worry about other fields or what was in the query: `let date = ret.date;
    if (date) {
      ret.date = date.getFullYear();
    }`

Comment: Is there anyways available for format date as custom using find query

Comment: @shankarmsr could you clarify your question?